# Copilot's inline suggestion suppresses quick suggestion widget in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot, inline-hints

In Visual Studio 2022, when GitHub Copilot suggests an inline hint, the quick suggestion widget will be suppressed, as shown in the following gif.
[image]
This annoys me a lot since sometimes I need to browse the suggestion widget to view code documentation, especially when using an unfamiliar framework.
Is there an option to prevent the inline hint from suppressing the suggestion widget? Or if someone else has already submitted the suggestion to Visual Studio, please show me the link, since I didn't find such issues in VS community myself.